# How do i convert the values in a List<PointF> from float to int?

Tags: c#, .net

For example in the List i have in index 0: {X = 100 , Y = 121.435454}
Then in index 1 i have: {X = 100 , Y = 121.433}

Now i want to loop over this convert all the coordinates to INT so in the end index 0 will look like:

```
{X = 100 , Y = 121}
```

And index 1 will be the same: {X = 100 , Y = 121}

After i loop over all the List and change all the coordinates numbers to int.
I want to filter and check that if there are places that X and Y are the same remove them and leave only one of them.

For example if after i converted all the List values to INT i see in index 0 1 and 2:

```
{X = 100 , Y = 121}
{X = 100 , Y = 121}
{X = 100 , Y = 121}
```

Then clean two of them and leave only one {X = 100 , Y = 121}

I did:

```
private static void RemoveSamePoints()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < extendedPoints.Count; i++)
    {
        extendedPoints = extendedPoints[i]
    }
}
```

How do i first convert the List numbers inside of each coordinate from float to int ?

EDIT

This is what i have tried now and its working and also correct i guess:

```
private static void RemoveSamePoints()
        {
            List<Point> PointsInt = new List<Point>();
            for (int i = 0; i < extendedPoints.Count; i++)
            {
                PointsInt.Add(new Point(Convert.ToInt32(extendedPoints[i].X), Convert.ToInt32(extendedPoints[i].Y)));
            }
        }
```

Comment: how does PointF look?

Comment: Do you want to round your values or truncate?

Comment: Every iteration through your loop you want to set the container variable itself defined as `List<PointF>` to one individual value?  Just one `PointF`?  If not, that's what your code says.  Note: As you describe it it shouldn't be compiling.  `extendedPoints[i].Y = Math.Round(extendedPoints[i].Y);`  Could be a start for the "cleanup" stage...

Comment: ebyrob no i don't want to convert it to one value of int. I want to keep the list format for example now the list is look like this in index 0 i see: {X = 120 , Y = 130.45456456} I want that after i convert it to int the same List will look like: {X = 120 , Y = 130} And the same thing for all the indexs in the PointF List. So in the maybe i will use another List type Point but in the end the List should look the same format as before coordinates of points but as int's So the new list Point will look like: {X = 120 , Y = 130}

Comment: Updated my question with what i tried and also working.

Comment: With your new code I know you likely removed a lot of code and you likely have a `.Distinct()` or something later on to remove the duplicates, however if you don't care about order use a `HashSet<Point>` instead of a `List<Point>` and it will take care of removing the duplicates for you (`Point` overrides `Equals(object obj)` for you already so it is fine to use in a `HashSet`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new List, iterate through the list and use Convert.ToInt32 to convert the values.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, assuming the variable `points` is of type `List<PointF>`:

```
points = points
    .Select(p => new PointF(Convert.ToInt32(p.X), Convert.ToInt32(p.Y)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is often used in C#:

```
Int32 integerValue = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(floatValue));
```